# What adjective describes a hospital with a broad specialization?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

In Austria there is a big hospital called *General hospital* ([Allgemeines Krankenhaus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vienna_General_Hospital)) with *general* meaning that in that hospital many different diseases are being treated.

Is there a word better than *general* and *universal* to describe a hospital, where virtually every possible ailment is treated?

Comment: Have a look at this wikipedia article. It seems like general hospital is the term you are looking for. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hospital#Types

Comment: **General hospital" is the term in the U.S., e.g., Massachusetts General. Mobile-friendly - Massachusetts General Hospital is named the #1 hospital in the nation by U.S. News & World Report ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the UK, these are indeed called *General Hospitals*. Here's one I know of...

[image]

Image from [Brighton Argus](http://www.theargus.co.uk/news/11484623.Campaigners_seek_legal_advice_over_changes_to_maternity_and_children_s_services/)

Comment: This term is not unknown in the United States either. It's not the exclusive term -- eg. A hospital won't necessarily have the word general in its name -- but it is used to an extent.

Answer (score 0):

Check ***super* hospital**.

From [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/super):

> **super**-
> *prefix*
>
> **Simple Definition** of **super**- : bigger, better, or more important than
> others of the same kind
>
> **Full Definition of super-**
>
> 1 a (1) :  over and above :  **higher in quantity**, quality, or degree
> than :  more than  (2) :  in addition :  **extra**
>
> b (1) :  exceeding or so as to **exceed a norm**
>
> c :  **surpassing all or most others of its kind**
>
> 4 :  constituting a **more inclusive category** than that specified

From [TFD](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/super+hospital):

> **super hospital**
>
> A mega-medical centre in the UK (e.g., Queen Elizabeth Hospital,
> Birmingham), built under a private finance initiative (PFI), *to
> provide tertiary care services within the same complex*.